# Android Search View Array becomes blacnk

Tags: android, searchview

I am trying to iterate through my array in searchview but when I start query by array becomes blank. I got my items from firebase realtime database. I am stack here for threee days and now finding no way I am writing.

private val db = Database(this)
val adapter = ShowAllTilesItems(this)

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

    var allTiles = ArrayList<Tile>()

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(binding.root)



    db.getAllTile {
        if (it != null) {
            allTiles= it
            adapter.run { getItems(it) }
        }

    }

    binding.mainRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    binding.mainRecyclerView.adapter = adapter


    binding.mainSearch.setOnQueryTextListener(object : OnQueryTextListener{
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            val filteredItems = ArrayList<Tile>()
            if (newText != null){
                for (i in allTiles){
                    if (i.code.contains(newText)){
                        filteredItems.add(i)
                    }
                }

                adapter.getItems(filteredItems)
            }


            return true
        }

    })

}
```